# DialogFlow Facebook Bot Pull URL

Tags: bots, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I have a bot in Facebook. I ask that the user provide her URL (copy, paste). Is it possible that I code the api.ai to do that automatically for me? Pull her URL, send to my database via webhook. 
Thanks!
Using api.ai (Dialogflow.com).

Comment: You will get facebook messenger id of messenger user of page. check the webhook request parameters.

Comment: Can I find their Facebook account with the messenger id number?